# undefined method `user_topics_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've been working on this for a while now and I'm about to go crazy. I have tables Users, Topics, and UserTopics. There is a `has_many` relationship between both Users and UserTopics, as well as between Topics and UserTopics. Currently I am getting the error:

```
undefined method `user_topics_path'
```

The line of code that is throwing the error is:

```
<%= form_for current_user.usertopics.find_by_user_id(@user),
         :html => { :method => :delete },
         :remote => true do |f| %>
```

In user.rb I have:

```
has_many :usertopics, :class_name => 'UserTopic', 
                      :foreign_key => "topic_id",
                      :dependent => :destroy
```

In routes.rb I have:

```
    resources :usertopics
```

From what I've gathered so far, the error lies within these pieces of code. I've tried other suggestions found around the web, to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route to be:

```
resources :user_topics
```

Comment: user_topics_path is generated by rails, I'm not sure if I'm really able to hard code it in.

Comment: And I just tried every combination I can think of inserted in `current_user.[here].find_by_user_id`.

Comment: I think you need to change your relationship to:

    `has_many :user_topics, :class_name => "UserTopic", :foreign_key => "topic_id", :dependent => :destroy`

and then your route to be

    `resources :user_topics`

Comment: What I did was change my route to `resources :user_topics`, but left `has_many...` the same. It now works! If you want to edit your answer to that, I'll ok it!

Comment: You're right, the relationship can stay the same since you've declared the class in your relationship definition.